# NextJS Stripe Webhook and Resend

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Does anyone know why sending emails doesn't work? i use resend, and i have add resend to my stripe webhook/route.ts file , if order was paid (completed) then i would like to send email, but it doesent work, and dropped no errors, and no logs, i tried same code on checkout/route.ts and email sending works but it send email even if the order has not been paid

```
    if (event.type === "checkout.session.completed") {
        
        const resend = new Resend(process.env.RESEND_API_KEY);
        await resend.emails.send({
            from: 'Order <no-reply@mysite.de>',
            to: ['client@gmail.com'],
            subject: 'Thank you for your Order',
            react: EmailTemplate({
              name: 'Test',
              orderid: '12435',
            }),
          });

}
```